# Did any Necrontyr survive enslavement by the C'tan?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I'm slowly reading through the Necron backstory in their Warhammer40K codex (5th edition).

One of the first things mentioned is the bio-transference of all the Necrontyr to be enslaved by the C'tan.

Did any of the necrontyr avoid this and survive to the present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt it, but it is possible. In the first war with the Old Ones, I believe the Necrontyr were pushed back to their home system, their colonies abandoned or destroyed. When they found the Death-C'tan on their home sun, and transferred it to a body, it demanded souls for its new hunger and subjugation. It took time to convince the C'tan that their were riper harvests outside of the system, and during that time, it ravaged the population.

They Necrons began preparing for a new war, more C'tan began to appear and transfer, and the Deceiver made the offer.

All I'm saying is that it is very unlikely, but then again the Old Ones survived somewhat, and I think that one or a group of said race are controlling the Tyranids for either vengence or to clean the galaxy.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that, form the ghost ark entry, most of the commoners were forced into the biotransference.

Comment: where is it mentioned that the old ones survived? (never read that before)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the Necrontyr willingly signed up as a species, my guess is that too few escaped the process to survive and propagate.

There are fringe theories that *Tau* are in fact Necrontyr, somehow. This has some merit, based on implications in the Necron codex and general similarities between the two species, but has no official confirmation whatsoever.

Comment: related to your supopstion: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22850/3804